# How to add a tag to a pushed commit afterwards?

Tags: git, tags, bitbucket, tortoisegit

I'm working in master branch. And what I tried to do is creating a tag for it. I made changes in the files. Afterwards I used this command line:

```
git tag -a <tag_name> -m "tag information and commit message"
```

This seemed to work. I used:

```
git describe --tags
```

to show which tag is used and it showed the correct one

Then I used TortoiseGit to commit my changes, I pulled and pushed and the tag-checkmarks were checked. But when I had a look at the Bitbucket repo the commit was made to the master branch. The tag was not passed.

Is there a way to add the tag afterwards (to local and remote) to this commit? I couldn't find anything yet. What would be the usual procedure to commit changes under a tag?

Comment: BTW the <tag_name> shouldn't contains spaces

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you push your tags to remote.

```
$ git push --tags
```

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thx! I thought tortoise git would take care of that since the tag-checkboxes were checked but it didn't. The tag-support and documentation for using tags in Tortoise Git is not so good...

Comment: I upvoted it but since it's an incomplete answer I won't accept it. For my problem I posted an answer which exactly does what I needed. And till now it's the best answer to the specific problem.

Answer (score 4):

Using `$> git push --tags` will push/transform **all** tags to remote server.

If your need is just to push a specific tag (because you have not already make a decision for other tags if you'll push them or they may be updated or removed later or just you don't want to share them with others *for now*), you can use:

```
$> git push origin <tag_name>
```

Comment: Thank you! My answer above already did the job. But in the future I will try to push correctly at the beginning

Answer (score 3):

**Create Tag and push it**

1. Open **TortoiseGit** `Log Message` dialog
2. Right click on the commit you want to tag, and click `Create Tag at this version...`
   [image]
3. File the `Tag name` and `Message`, something like:
   [image]
   Then, you have that tag on local
4. Back to `Log Message` dialog, right click on that tag label, click `Push "tag_name"...`
   [image]
5. `Push` dialog shows up, check all options are good to go, then push `OK` button
   [image]
   Then, you have that tag on remote

---

**Use Sync dialog to compare tags between local and remote**

If you can't push some tags, try to use `Compare tags`.

1. Right click on git repository, and click `Git Sync...`
   [image]
2. Use the `Compare tags` function, see:
   [image]
3. If there is already the same name tag on remote, it might shows: (NOTE: this is just one case of all.)
   [image]
   First of all, you have to know the fact that: **tag reference** points to a **tag object**, and **tag object** points to a **commit object** when you see `^{}`.
   So, as you can see, **tag object** `tag_name^{}` points to commit `0bd2bfa` both on local and remote.
   But, the **tag reference** `tag_name` points to different **tag objects**
   The local **tag reference** `tag_name` points to `d443bd1` which is a **tag object**
   The remote **tag reference** `tag_name` points to `f6c05b7` which is another **tag object**.
4. If you are sure the tag on remote is wrong, you can delete it from `Sync` dialog
   [image]
5. Then you can push local one to remote from `Sync` dialog:
   [image]
6. Now, it's identical
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution:

```
git tag -a <tag_name> <beginning of the commit hash shown in bitbucket> -m "a commit message"
git push --tags
```

I used another tag then originally. But if you want to use the same you have to delete it first:
local with:

```
git tag -d <tag name>
```

remote:

```
git push --delete origin <tag name>
```